# Calculation error, help me find please?

Tags: php, debugging

I am running subscriptions on my website.
I have a 1,3,6 and 12 months of subscription, and I would like the user to be able to change that subscription whenever they feel like.
However, I need to calculate the amount of money the user had to pay had he or she signed up for the shorter term, rather the relatively cheap,longer one.

I made this function `optimized_subscription_total($active_sub_time,$arr_sub_values)` so that it returns that sum of money exactly.

```
<?php 


function optimized_subscription_total($active_sub_time,$arr_sub_values)
{

    // This function takes a row from the DB where prices for each period of time usage is listed. there are prices for 1 month, 3 months,6 and 12 months.

    // when the user has subscribed for 12 months, and the user asks for a refund, after they used 9 months and 6 days for example, the system treats the refund as if they subscribed for (in months) COST_6 + COST_3 + (COST_1/30)*6 
    // the result of the function is then subtracted from the amount they actually paid and is considered the refund.

    // $arr_sub_values is the associative row from the DB, containing the prices
    // $active_sub_time is measured in months and is a double

$result=0;


while(($active_sub_time-12)>=0)
{
    $active_sub_time-=12;
    $result+=($arr_subscription_values['COST_12']);
}

while(($active_sub_time-6)>=0)
{
    $active_sub_time-=6;
    $result+=($arr_subscription_values['COST_6']);
}
while(($active_sub_time-3)>=0)
{
    $active_sub_time-=3;
    $result+=($arr_subscription_values['COST_3']);
}

while(($active_sub_time-1)>=0)
{
    $active_sub_time-=1;
    $result+=($arr_subscription_values['COST_1']);
}

if($active_sub_time>0)
    $result+=($active_sub_time)*($arr_subscription_values['COST_1']);

return $result;

}



$datetime1 = date_create('2009-12-11');
$datetime2 = date_create('2010-11-09');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
$num_of_months = ($interval->format('%y'))*12+($interval->format('%m'))+($interval->format('%a'))/30;
echo "<br />";

$v = array('COST_1'=>'3.99','COST_3'=>'9.99','COST_6'=>'15.99','COST_12'=>'25.99');
echo "OPT value for $num_of_months months=" . optimized_subscription_total($num_of_months, $v);


?>
```

Strangely I get the bug appearing **only after 7 to 10 times after refreshing** this code.
So I got:

```
OPT value for 10 months=M.97
```

as a result here. I think I need to get a float number, no ?

I was expecting the result of the function that should be "OPT value for 10 months=29.97", as it should take COST_6 + COST_3 + COST_1... but I get that weird M.97, and sometimes things like POKHHHG.97

Comment: He changes from what to what? For example I am on 12 Month subscription, I am in 2nd Month and now I changed subscription to 3 months, where do you store all these values?

Comment: This is only some overview about what this function is being used for. If you paid 25.99 for the whole year (12 months), and bail out or upgrade after 7 months, you are considered as if you had the 6 months + 1 months. and get your refund from the previous 25.99 that you already paid. Here you can see that it is : refund=25.99-(15.99+3.99)=6.01 If you take this function and run it, after 10 times you can see that the output is buggy. like "OPT value for 10 months=M.97
", where the M.97 is weird. I am trying to figure out what is causing that.

Comment: I did not test the code because I dont have a PHP server at the moment, if things are still bothering you, let me know.

Comment: yes. still happens... This must be a memory leak somehow

Answer (score 0):

I would change the logic to the following and see if error is still produced. I think this is a little bit more clear and easy to debug. It is the same as your though just explained differently.

```
while($active_sub_time>=12)
{
    $active_sub_time-=12;
    $result+=($arr_subscription_values['COST_12']);
}

while($active_sub_time>=6)
{
    $active_sub_time-=6;
    $result+=($arr_subscription_values['COST_6']);
}
while($active_sub_time>=3)
{
    $active_sub_time-=3;
    $result+=($arr_subscription_values['COST_3']);
}

while($active_sub_time>=1)
{
    $active_sub_time-=1;
    $result+=($arr_subscription_values['COST_1']);
}
```

What I would also do is added debug cod at the top inside function.

```
echo "<br>$active_sub_time" // debug code include at the top
```

This will give you an idea, if any garbage being is being sent to the function itself.

Also I would add this test function in all while blocks if the above does not resolve the issue.

```
if (!is_numeric($result))
{
    echo"<br> Bug occurred";break; // print other values if necessary
}
```

Comment: Thanks @The crocodile hunter, I just added the is_numeric to the function tail. It is so weird, that I get that value printed out (now as I.00425), but the server treats it normally, it just prints is out that way. the gettype I get for it is a double. Did the function return wrong values for you too ?